# What are the fundamental differences between set and didSet?

Tags: swift

I understand that one is a setter and the other is a property observer. My question is how do they differ in behavior and when would you use one over the other. Don't they do pretty much the same thing? For example:

```
var foo: String {
 set {
   run code when set
 }
}

var foo: String {
 didSet {
  run code when set
 }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

They do not do pretty much the same thing, on the contrary they have totally different purposes. The `get` and the `set` are used on computed properties. For instance, take this example structure that has no real use, but is a good demo.

```
struct test {
    var x = 5
    var y = 5
    var number: Int {
        get {
            return x * y
        }
        set (newValue){
            x = newValue / 2
            y = newValue / 2
        }
    }
}

var s = test()
s.number //25
s.number = 100
s.x //50
s.number //2500
```

So, as you can see, the variable `number` isn't a variable in the traditional sense, it is a computed property. So, when I call `s.number` I get the product of x and y. Also, you would use the set to change other variables (not the computed property itself) in the structure. So, I set `x` and `y` to different values based on the `newValue`. This idea of a computed property can be used in place of a function and I find is very useful in simplifying retrieval of data from a function. For instance, you could have a structure that has a distance in kilometers and you might want that in miles very frequently. So, you could create a computed property `miles` for miles that computes the number of kilometers with the `get` method, and changes the number of kilometers with the setter if a you set miles to in your program.

---

Now, for the `didSet` and `willSet`. You can use these to notify your structure of a value change. For instance, an averageTracker.

```
struct averageTracker {
    var total: Double = 0 {
        didSet {
            numEntries++
        }
    }
    var numEntries: Double = 0
    var average: Double {
        get {
            return total / numEntries
        }
    }
}


var ave = averageTracker()
ave.total += 10
ave.total += 20
ave.average //15
```

Notice how the `didSet` is actually on a variable that contains a value, that is, it is not a computed property. Also, I used a computed property `average` to get the average. Overall, I hope I cleared up your confusion regarding this very powerful aspect of Swift.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing. :)

set {} is calling when you initialise value, but not disSet {}

```
var x : Int = 0 {
  set {
    print(x)
  }
}
...
x = 1
```

produce "0" and "1" output.

But didSet not so.

```
var x : Int = 0 {
  didSet {
    print(x)
  }
}
...
x = 1
```

have not call before you change value.
Only "1" result will be printed, not "0" and "1"

It can be as useful, so bug source.

Comment: I think this is not true.. stored properties cannot have set.. also set and didSet you can not use at the same time..