# When to use didset or get set when using @IBInspectable

Tags: swift

After looking at different tutorial. i don't know when to use didset or get set to update the variable.
Could anyone explain a little bit more detail for when to use didset or get set?

```
 @IBInspectable var circleColor: UIColor = UIColor.redColor() {
    didSet { //after properties are set in storyboard, update here
        circleLayer.strokeColor = circleColor.CGColor
        self.toggleButon()
    }
}
/**
    Radius of RadioButton circle.
*/
@IBInspectable var circleRadius: CGFloat = 5.0
@IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
    get {
        return layer.cornerRadius
    }
    set {
        layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
    }
}
```

for circle radius, it doesn't have to use didset to update its value. i can't get it.

Answer (score 0):

### Here i am giving you one example and try to explain you how to use, hope it will helpful for you.

#### I am using this class for UIView here for did set and get set with Story Board my class name here "MyCustomView"

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

/// Computed properties, based on the backing CALayer property, that are visible in Interface Builder.
@IBDesignable public class MyCustomView: UIView {
    /// When positive, the background of the layer will be drawn with rounded corners. Also effects the mask generated by the `masksToBounds' property. Defaults to zero. Animatable.
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: Double {
        get {
            return Double(self.layer.cornerRadius)
        }
        set {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(newValue)
        }
    }
    
    /// The width of the layer's border, inset from the layer bounds. The border is composited above the layer's content and sublayers and includes the effects of the `cornerRadius' property. Defaults to zero. Animatable.
    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: Double {
        get {
            return Double(self.layer.borderWidth)
        }
        set {
            self.layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(newValue)
        }
    }
    
    /// The color of the layer's border. Defaults to opaque black. Colors created from tiled patterns are supported. Animatable.
    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            return UIColor(CGColor: self.layer.borderColor!)
        }
        set {
            self.layer.borderColor = newValue?.CGColor
        }
    }
    
    /// The color of the shadow. Defaults to opaque black. Colors created from patterns are currently NOT supported. Animatable.
    @IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            return UIColor(CGColor: self.layer.shadowColor!)
        }
        set {
            self.layer.shadowColor = newValue?.CGColor
        }
    }
    
    /// The opacity of the shadow. Defaults to 0. Specifying a value outside the [0,1] range will give undefined results. Animatable.
    @IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float {
        get {
            return self.layer.shadowOpacity
        }
        set {
            self.layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
        }
    }
    
    /// The shadow offset. Defaults to (0, -3). Animatable.
    @IBInspectable var shadowOffset: CGSize {
        get {
            return self.layer.shadowOffset
        }
        set {
            self.layer.shadowOffset = newValue
        }
    }
    
    /// The blur radius used to create the shadow. Defaults to 3. Animatable.
    @IBInspectable var shadowRadius: Double {
        get {
            return Double(self.layer.shadowRadius)
        }
        set {
            self.layer.shadowRadius = CGFloat(newValue)
        }
    }
}
```

And you can use this with story board import this class with your "UIView"

[image]

after you will see some
and you directly set here view cornet radius, shadow and Shadow

[image]

and result you can see inside your storyboard directly without running code

### Output here from this code

[image]

Comment: in my sample code, it doesn't have to use didset or getset to update the circle radius. but i can also change it by setting in storyboard. so i can't get it

Comment: Please check you imported inside you UIView like @IBDesignable public class ClassName of your IBDesignable? otherwise you can use my code.

Comment: i think you get me wrong. i am trying to say i that i can change the circle radius in attributes inspector even though i didn't use didset or getset to update the value in my code

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33092733/5490952)  explains the difference in usage of `set` vs `didSet` quite clearly.

**IN SUMMARY**

`willSet` should be used for doing something before the value is set. (the value is not updated at this point).

`set` is to update the value

`didSet` if you want to do anything after the value is set (the value has been updated at this point)

**ALSO**

if you implement `set`, you will also need to implement `get`

but `didSet` can also be used without having to implement any other method

Answer (score 0):

***@IBInspectable*** will work with ***both*** property kinds:

- Use didSet{} for ***stored properties***:

  didSet is a property observer.
- Use ***set{} get{}*** for ***computed properties***.

in the following example: firstName And lastName are stored properties.

fullName is a Computed property:

```
struct Person{
    var firstName:String
    var lastName:String{
        didSet{
            //property observer
            print("It was set")
        }
    }

    var fullName:String{
        get{
            return "\(firstName)-\(lastName)"
        }
        set{
            let split = newValue.split(separator: "-")

            firstName = String(split.first ?? "")
            lastName = String(split.last ?? "")
        }
    }
}

var p = Person(firstName: "Moshe", lastName: "Doe")

print(p.firstName)
print(p.lastName)
print(p.fullName)

p.fullName = "Jhon-Doe"

print(p.firstName)
print(p.lastName)
print(p.fullName)
```

Also look into the language guide: (Properties)

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html

One final note about properties and ***@IBInspectable***:
Validation of a value may be achieved using a combo of a computed property with a stored property (Backing property): Here is an example:

```
//Bound between 0 and 5
var boundRating:Int = 3{
    didSet{
        renderRating()
    }
}

@IBInspectable
var rating:Int{
    set{
        if newValue <= 5 && newValue >= 0{
            boundRating = newValue
            renderRating()
        }
    }
    get{
        return boundRating
    }
}
```