# Swift IBInspectable didSet versus get/set

Tags: swift, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

I am relatively new to `IBDesignables` and `IBInspectable`'s and I noticed that a lot of tutorial use `IBInspectable` in this fashion.

```
@IBInspectable var buttonBorderWidth: CGFloat = 1.0 {
    didSet {
        updateView()
    }
}

func updateView() {
    // Usually there are more entries here for each IBInspectable
    self.layer.borderWidth = buttonBorderWidth
}
```

But in some instances they use get and set like this for example

```
@IBInspectable
var shadowOpacity: Float {
    get {
        return layer.shadowOpacity
    }
    set {
        layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain: What is happening in each of these cases and how to choose which one to use?

Comment: I think this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091926/what-are-the-fundamental-differences-between-set-and-didset

Answer (score 5):

I see two questions. The first one is “What is happening in each of these cases”, and is best answered by reading [the “Properties” chapter of *The Swift Programming Language*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html). There are also already three other answers posted which address the first question, but none of them answer the second, and more interesting, question.

The second question is “how to choose which one to use”.

Your `shadowOpacity` example (which is a computed property) has the following advantages over your `buttonBorderWidth` example (which is a stored property with an observer):

- All of the `shadowOpacity`-related code is in one place, so it's easier to understand how it works. The `buttonBorderWidth` code is spread between `didSet` and `updateViews`. In a real program these functions are more likely to be farther apart, and as you said, “Usually there are more entries here for each IBInspectable”. This makes it harder to find and understand all the code involved in implementing `buttonBorderWidth`.
- Since the view's `shadowOpacity` property getter and setter just forward to the layer's property, the view's property doesn't take any additional space in the view's memory layout. The view's `buttonBorderWidth`, being a stored property, does take additional space in the view's memory layout.

There is an advantage to the separate `updateViews` here, but it is subtle. Notice that `buttonBorderWidth` has a default value of 1.0. This is different than the default value of `layer.borderWidth`, which is 0. Somehow we need to get `layer.borderWidth` to match `buttonBorderWidth` when the view is initialized, even if `buttonBorderWidth` is never modified. Since the code that sets `layer.borderWidth` is in `updateViews`, we can just make sure we call `updateViews` at some point before the view is displayed (e.g. in `init` or in `layoutSubviews` or in `willMove(toWindow:)`).

If we want to make `buttonBorderWidth` be a computed property instead, we either have to force-set the `buttonBorderWidth` to its existing value somewhere, or duplicate the code that sets `layer.borderWidth` somewhere. That is, we either have to do something like this:

```
init(frame: CGRect) {
    ...

    super.init(frame: frame)

    // This is cumbersome because:
    // - init won't call buttonBorderWidth.didSet by default.
    // - You can't assign a property to itself, e.g. `a = a` is banned.
    // - Without the semicolon, the closure is treated as a trailing
    //   closure on the above call to super.init().
    ;{ buttonBorderWidth = { buttonBorderWidth }() }()
}
```

Or we have to do something like this:

```
init(frame: CGRect) {
    ...

    super.init(frame: frame)

    // This is the same code as in buttonBorderWidth.didSet:
    layer.borderWidth = buttonBorderWidth
}
```

And if we have a bunch of these properties that cover layer properties but have different default values, we have to do this force-setting or duplicating for each of them.

My solution to this is generally to not have a different default value for my inspectable property than for the property it covers. If we just let the default value of `buttonBorderWidth` be 0 (same as the default for `layer.borderWidth`), then we don't have to get the two properties in sync because they're never out-of-sync. So I would just implement `buttonBorderWidth` like this:

```
@IBInspectable var buttonBorderWidth: CGFloat {
    get { return layer.borderWidth }
    set { layer.borderWidth = newValue }
}
```

So, **when would you want to use a stored property with an observer?** One condition especially applicable to `IBInspectable` is when the inspectable properties do not map trivially onto existing layer properties.

For example, in iOS 11 and macOS 10.13 and later, `CALayer` has a `maskedCorners` property that controls which corners are rounded by `cornerRadius`. Suppose we want to expose both `cornerRadius` and `maskedCorners` as inspectable properties. We might as well just expose `cornerRadius` using a computed property:

```
@IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
    get { return layer.cornerRadius }
    set { layer.cornerRadius = newValue }
}
```

But `maskedCorners` is essentially four different boolean properties combined into one. So we should expose it as four separate inspectable properties. If we use computed properties, it looks like this:

```
@IBInspectable var isTopLeftCornerRounded: Bool {
    get { return layer.maskedCorners.contains(.layerMinXMinYCorner) }
    set {
        if newValue { layer.maskedCorners.insert(.layerMinXMinYCorner) }
        else { layer.maskedCorners.remove(.layerMinXMinYCorner) }
    }
}

@IBInspectable var isBottomLeftCornerRounded: Bool {
    get { return layer.maskedCorners.contains(.layerMinXMaxYCorner) }
    set {
        if newValue { layer.maskedCorners.insert(.layerMinXMaxYCorner) }
        else { layer.maskedCorners.remove(.layerMinXMaxYCorner) }
    }
}

@IBInspectable var isTopRightCornerRounded: Bool {
    get { return layer.maskedCorners.contains(.layerMaxXMinYCorner) }
    set {
        if newValue { layer.maskedCorners.insert(.layerMaxXMinYCorner) }
        else { layer.maskedCorners.remove(.layerMaxXMinYCorner) }
    }
}

@IBInspectable var isBottomRightCornerRounded: Bool {
    get { return layer.maskedCorners.contains(.layerMaxXMaxYCorner) }
    set {
        if newValue { layer.maskedCorners.insert(.layerMaxXMaxYCorner) }
        else { layer.maskedCorners.remove(.layerMaxXMaxYCorner) }
    }
}
```

That's a bunch of repetitive code. It's easy to miss something if you write it using copy and paste. (I don't guarantee that I got it correct!) Now let's see what it looks like using stored properties with observers:

```
@IBInspectable var isTopLeftCornerRounded = true {
    didSet { updateMaskedCorners() }
}

@IBInspectable var isBottomLeftCornerRounded = true {
    didSet { updateMaskedCorners() }
}

@IBInspectable var isTopRightCornerRounded = true {
    didSet { updateMaskedCorners() }
}

@IBInspectable var isBottomRightCornerRounded = true {
    didSet { updateMaskedCorners() }
}

private func updateMaskedCorners() {
    var mask: CACornerMask = []
    if isTopLeftCornerRounded { mask.insert(.layerMinXMinYCorner) }
    if isBottomLeftCornerRounded { mask.insert(.layerMinXMaxYCorner) }
    if isTopRightCornerRounded { mask.insert(.layerMaxXMinYCorner) }
    if isBottomRightCornerRounded { mask.insert(.layerMaxXMaxYCorner) }
    layer.maskedCorners = mask
}
```

I think this version with stored properties has several advantages over the version with computed properties:

- The parts of the code that are repeated are much shorter.
- Each mask option is only mentioned once, so it's easier to make sure the options are all correct.
- All the code that actually computes the mask is in one place.
- The mask is constructed entirely from scratch each time, so you don't have to know the mask's prior value to understand what its new value will be.

Here's another example where I'd use a stored property: suppose you want to make a `PolygonView` and make the number of sides be inspectable. We need code to create the path given the number of sides, so here it is:

```
extension CGPath {
    static func polygon(in rect: CGRect, withSideCount sideCount: Int) -> CGPath {
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        guard sideCount >= 3 else {
            return path
        }

        // It's easiest to compute the vertices of a polygon inscribed in the unit circle.
        // So I'll do that, and use this transform to inscribe the polygon in `rect` instead.
        let transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            .translatedBy(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY) // translate to the rect's origin
            .scaledBy(x: rect.width, y: rect.height) // scale up to the rect's size
            .scaledBy(x: 0.5, y: 0.5) // unit circle fills a 2x2 box but we want a 1x1 box
            .translatedBy(x: 1, y: 1) // lower left of unit circle's box is at (-1, -1) but we want it at (0, 0)

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0), transform: transform)
        for i in 1 ..< sideCount {
            let angle = CGFloat(i) / CGFloat(sideCount) * 2 * CGFloat.pi
            print("\(i) \(angle)")
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: cos(angle), y: sin(angle)), transform: transform)
        }
        path.closeSubpath()

        print("rect=\(rect) path=\(path.boundingBox)")
        return path
    }
}
```

We could write code that takes a `CGPath` and counts the number of segments it draws, but it is simpler to just store the number of sides directly. So in this case, it makes sense to use a stored property with an observer that triggers an update to the layer path:

```
class PolygonView: UIView {

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass { return CAShapeLayer.self }

    @IBInspectable var sideCount: Int = 3 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        (layer as! CAShapeLayer).path = CGPath.polygon(in: bounds, withSideCount: sideCount)
    }

}
```

I update the path in `layoutSubviews` because I also need to update the path if the view's size changes, and a size change also triggers `layoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what you are asking about is nothing to do with `@IBInspectable` or `@IBDesignable`.  Those are just directives for XCode to use with the Interface Builder when you create your own View/ViewControllers.  Any property with `@IBInspectable` also appears in the  *attributes inspector* in the Interface Builder. And `@IBDesignable` is for displaying the custom view in Interface builder. Now to get to the `didSet` and `get/set`

- `didSet`
  This is what you call a Property Observer. You can define property observers for a stored property to monitor the changes in a property. There are 2 flavors to monitor the change `willSet` and `didSet`that can be defined.  So you define the observers to perform some block of code where there is a change to that property. If you define `willSet` that code will be called before the property is set. Likewise `didSet` is the block run after the property has been set. So depending on what you need to do you can implement either of the observers.
- `get/set`
  Besides stored properties you can define something called Computed properties. As the name implies computed properties do not create and store any values themselves. These values are computed when needed. So these properties need `get` and `set` code to compute the property when required. If there is only a `get` that means it’s a read only property.

Hope this helps. Read the Swift book and go through the first few lectures of CS193p on iTunesU

Answer (score 0):

`didSet` means "do the following when the variable is set". In your case, if you change `buttonBorderWidth`, the function `updateView()` will be called.

`get` and `set` are what you actually get when you ask for the variable itself. If I set `shadowOpacity`, it will pass it on to the `set` code. If I get `shadowOpacity`, it will actually get me `layer.shadowOpacity`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBInspectable var buttonBorderWidth: CGFloat = 1.0
```

In that example, `buttonBorderWidth` is an actual property of the view. The attributes inspector can write to it and read it directly. The `didSet` observer is just so that something happens in response to our changing that property.

That's totally different from the other example:

```
@IBInspectable
var shadowOpacity: Float {
    get {
        return layer.shadowOpacity
    }
    set {
        layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
    }
}
```

In that example, the goal is to make the *layer's* `shadowOpacity` inspectable. But you can't do that, because it's not a property of the view. Therefore we put a *façade* in front of the layer property, in the form of a computed "property" of the view; the attributes inspector can't see `layer.shadowOpacity`, but it can see the *view's* `shadowOpacity` which, unbeknownst to it, is just a way of accessing the layer's `shadowOpacity`.